# Открытый порт 25 наружу?

Tags: unix, smtp

Развернул ubuntu 16.04 на VPS.
Проверяю, какие порты открыты. Вижу, что наружу светится 25 порт.
Я понимаю, что это почтовый сервер.
Возникает вопрос - нужна ли это служба вообще?
Или оставить включенной, но закрыть порт наружу, чтобы только для локалхоста был доступ?

netstat:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      491/master
```

nmap:

```
RT   STATE    SERVICE
25/tcp filtered smtp
```

Comment: Это входящая почта. Если вам надо что бы ваш почтовый сервер принимал почту из вне порт должен быть открыт

Comment: На данный момент изменил в конфиге postfix на локалхост. Вопрос в другом - мне вообще не надо почтовый сервер. Если я его снесу, не будет потом проблем с работой каких-то других пакетов?

Comment: Могут быть. Многие программы (например, крон или sudo) рассчитывают на существование MTA на хосте, чтобы отправлять сообщения о проблемах.

Comment: Я бы даже сказал, что не "могут быть проблемы", а обязательно будут. тот же cron требует наличие какого нибудь отправщика почты (MTA). другое дело, что есть более легие версии для этих целей, что бы postfix не держать, но не помню как они называются.

Comment: Ага понятно. Остался только один маленький вопрос - а зачем по дефолту этот порт делать открытым во вне? Как по мне - лишний открытый порт - это такая маленькая (а иногда и не очень) дырка твоей секурности.

Comment: SMTP не подразумевает никакого remote execution, поэтому это просто точка приема писем. Если у постфикса в конфигурации указана опция mynetworks только с локальными сетями, то потенциальному злоумышленнику это вообще ничего не дает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сам факт того, что у вас возникает вопрос — нужна ли вам та или иная (постоянно работающая) программа, говорит о том, что она вам не нужна.

но, вполне возможно, функциональность этой программа нужна каким-либо другим программам (возможно, через цепочку зависимостей), про которые вы точно знаете, что они вам нужны.

простейший способ узнать, существует ли такая зависимость — остановить работу этой программы (в вашем конкретном случае, скорее всего, подойдёт команда вроде `$ sudo /etc/init.d/postfix stop`), и убедиться, что все нужные вам программы продолжают выполнять все нужные вам функции.

если «всё в порядке», то можете удалять пакет с этой программой (пример команды не привожу, так как это дистрибутиво-специфично — ищите информацию по примерно такому запросу: «<дистрибутив> как удалить пакет»)

Comment: «убедиться, что все нужные вам программы продолжают выполнять все нужные вам функции» — те же cron и sudo продолжат работать, пока не возникнет какой-нибудь ошибки, так что совет в целом так себе

Comment: @andreymal, неудачный пример. обе программы (и *crond* и *sudo*) отлично функционируют (как пример) без какой-либо программы, реализующей фукнциональность *smtp*-сервера. // если же нужна доставка писем куда-то за пределы компьютера, то выполняется условие: «программа, реализующая smtp, вам нужна».